# openlayers display projection

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2, display

I'm displaying coordinates in EPSG:900913 using `ol.control.MousePosition()` with OSM.
I'd like to convert these on the fly in another EPSG:2154.

I call in the header :

```
<script src="./proj4js-1-1-0/lib/proj4js-compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then my html :

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2154"] = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";

var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        projection: "EPSG:900913",
        controls:[
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false}),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({
                    'geodesic': "true"
                }),
                 new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                 new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
                 new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(
                     {displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2154")}
                 )
                ]
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenLayers won't know the definitions of the projections just because of the included Proj4js script. The projections which [OpenLayers 2 supports](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Projection-js.html) natively are the following: EPSG:4326, CRS:84, urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.6:4326, EPSG:900913, EPSG:3857, EPSG:102113 and EPSG:102100. If you have to use an other projection, you have to define the coordinate system manually before using it in OpenLayers. You can look up references for projections on [spatailreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/).

The definition of the [EPSG:2154](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/rgf93-lambert-93/) is the following:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

So before you can use this projection in OpenLayers, you have to define it in your code first like this:

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2154"] = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
```

Or if you want to go the lazy way you can include Proj4js's [predefined projection file](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/rgf93-lambert-93/proj4js/) as a script in your header:

```
<script src="http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/rgf93-lambert-93/proj4js/" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/9cgz3Lcd/) to show the process. I have used OSM in it, which uses EPSG:900913, [similar to EPSG:3857](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857).

Comment: Thx. I added <script src="http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/rgf93-lambert-93/proj4js/" type="text/javascript"></script> in the header and got the message "Proj4js is not defined". I can't figure out the reason. But I have read this http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/OpenLayers-do-not-detect-Proj4js-td5102276.html, sort of compatibility issue. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Yes, it can make sense. Try to use Proj4js 1.x instead. When I'll have some time, I will try it, too. Maybe Proj4js 2.x's methods and output differs from 1.x versions and 2.x is only implemented in OL3.

Comment: I tried with proj4js1.1.0 : it works. But now of course, 3857 is unknown : I have some problem to define 3857 with the proj4js.defs. Should it be written between <script> in the header ?

Comment: You only have to include external resources in an individual <script> tag. EPSG:3857 is a default projection in OpenLayers 2 (in theory), so you only have to define EPSG:2154. If you use an external script file, you have to include it, otherwise you can define it in your code with the Proj4js.defs function. If nobody can get a working result until evening, I will take a look, too.

Comment: I updated the code in first post. So now I can read coordinates in 2154 but still have "NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3857/proj4js/". It is weird because if it doesn't know 3857, how can it reproject it in 2154 ??

Comment: If it can't use EPSG:3857 natively, then you can reference to it as "SR-ORG:6864" with the following referencing script: http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/proj4js/

Comment: I created a EPSG3857.js in the lib directory, added the script in header (code updated) and still have "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://10.3.1.51/proj4js-1-1-0/lib/defs/EPSG3857.js". Note that if i put the file in defs, error still appears with other path. I

Comment: Because I couldn't find any WMS map that uses EPSG:3857, I have used OSM, which uses EPSG:900913, similar to 3857 (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857). Are the transformed coordinates correct on the map? You can see the external resources I have used in the corresponding tab. http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/9cgz3Lcd/

Comment: Thx. Transformed coordinates are correct. I will try to use your jsfiddle as model.

Comment: Done. No error left since i used 900913. Updated my code to be useful. Thanks all